# How can I determine what is attempting to use sendmail/postfix on ML?

Tags: macos, email

I'm getting console messages multiple times per day that look like this:

```
8/2/13 5:20:00.119 PM postfix/sendmail[31004]: fatal: chdir /Library/Server/Mail/Data/spool: No such file or directory
```

When I tail /var/log/mail.log I see the same messages. According to the postfix config, the spool is indeed pointing to this directory, and yes, it does not exist.

```
queue_directory = /Library/Server/Mail/Data/spool
```

The thing is, I don't want postfix to be running, and have no idea why it's throwing errors. I'm not listening on port 25 as per netstat and I don't see any postfix processes running.

What's causing the error? Why would I get it if postfix isn't running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have postfix installed and running.

You should check your postfix configuration.

There is a good description [here](http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html#myorigin).

Or do it your self:
If postfix is still not working, check the log file in /var/log/mail.log for the error:

> sendmail: fatal: chdir /Library/Server/Mail/Data/spool: No such file
>   or directory

To fix this, run the following commands in Terminal:

```
sudo mkdir -p /Library/Server/Mail/Data/spool
sudo /usr/sbin/postfix set-permissions
sudo /usr/sbin/postfix start
```

If as you say you do not want it to be on your computer then disable it.

```
sudo /bin/launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.postfix.master.plist
```

That does not answer your question who is using it, but without more info from you one can not say, it could be a script in your system.

You could try to find out who is sending by going to

Open your Console:

Scroll down to `Var/Log/mail.log`

> The background: Mac OSX comes with the postfix MTA, which is a fully
>   featured SMTP server. Under normal circumstances, there is usually no
>   need to enable or configure this software, as most email access is
>   usually done via GUI clients such as the Mail.app – which uses the
>   POP/IMAP and SMTP settings to connect with the email service provider.
>   However, there are certain circumstances in which having a local SMTP
>   server is very useful, such as: Allowing the batch logs and output
>   from the cron daemon or other scripts to be sent via Internet email
>   (this is otherwise delivered locally) Testing email based code; which
>   requires a local sendmail like SMTP server to be present

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ran `sudo /bin/launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.postfix.master.plist` but a half an hour later received another of the same sendmail errors in console

Comment: Try using the Fix as described above first to eliminate the error. Than we can go about finding who is sending the mail.

Comment: Creating the directory and restarting / stopping postfix did indeed stop the console errors. Since postfix remains stopped, I guess nothing will be sending mail. Problem solved.